# How to pass arguments to webpack.conf.js?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm following [these](https://www.hipstercode.com/blog/27/) instructions based on [this](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/tree/master/template) project (the official Vue Webpack template).

This is what I did:

**package.js:**

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "node build/dev-server.js",
  "dev-alt": "node build/dev-server.js && set arg=alt&&webpack"
},
```

**webpack.base.config.js:**

```
// npm run dev-alt in the terminal 
console.log('ARGS:', process.env.arg)
```

However `ARGS:` outputs `undefined`.

What the correct way to do this?

Comment: try process.argv with `node build/dev-server.js --arg alt&&webpack`

Comment: Hey it worked. Could you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass whatever arguments you want by:

`node my-script.js --myArgs thisIsTheValue`

In my-script.js you can retrieve arguments by:

```
function getArg(key, defaultVal) {
    var index = process.argv.indexOf(key),
        next = process.argv[index + 1];

    defaultVal = defaultVal || null;

    return (index < 0) ? defaultVal : (!next || next[0] === "-") ? true : next;
}

var theArgsIWant = getArg('--myArgs', 'this is the default if argument not found');
```

Answer (score 27):

With Webpack `5.x` and above you can no longer pass custom arguments to Webpack like `--myarg=val`. But you can still pass the supported arguments like `--mode=production`.

So what's the solution for custom args? Instead we need to write it like this, using the new `--env` parameter.

```js
  "build-project": webpack --mode=production --env myarg=val --env otherarg=val
```

Note that the custom arguments no longer start with `--` after we put `--env` ahead of them. You'll need to put `--env` ahead of each custom key/value pair you need to define.

---

You'll also need to modify your Webpack config to export a function, rather than an object.

See this example code, [taken from the docs.](https://webpack.js.org/guides/environment-variables/)

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = (env) => {
  // Use env.<YOUR VARIABLE> here:
  console.log('NODE_ENV: ', env.NODE_ENV); // 'local'
  console.log('Production: ', env.production); // true

  return {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
      filename: 'bundle.js',
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
  };
};
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you need to add `--env` before each argument you declare. You might only need to define it once, as long as all your non-Webpack-included arguments come before it.

Answer (score 5):

Pass webpack arguments with `--key=value` in `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
 "build": "webpack --mode=production --browser=firefox",
}
```

Access `argv` in `webpack.config.js` like this

```
module.exports = (env, argv) => {
  if (argv.mode == "development") {
  }

  if (argv.browser == "firefox") {
  }
};
```

Comment: This no longer works in Webpack@5.x and up.

Comment: it works. see https://github.com/GorvGoyl/Notion-Boost-browser-extension

Comment: From webpack@5: `webpack --env browser=firefox`

Answer (score 2):

From the article you described:

```
"scripts": {
  "webpack-quizMaker": "set arg=quizMaker&&webpack",
  "webpack-quiz": "set arg=quiz&&webpack"
}
```

These scritps are doing 2 things:

- They are setting an environment variable in a way that only works on Windows if you're not using PowerShell. It's recommend to use cross-env here.
- They are running `webpack` after setting the envinronment variable.

Then, inside the webpack configuration, they are reading the environment variable:

```
if (process.env.arg == "quiz") {
    // do your thing
}

if (process.env.arg == "quizMaker") {
     // do your thing
};
```

I recommend that you install [cross-env](https://github.com/kentcdodds/cross-env)

```
npm install --save-dev cross-env
```

And replace the scripts with this:

```
"scripts": {
  "webpack-quizMaker": "cross-env arg=\"quizMaker\" webpack",
  "webpack-quiz": "set arg=\"quiz\" webpack"
}
```

No need for `&&` anymore because `cross-env` will call the specified command (`webpack`) after setting the env variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
const onlyJS = process.argv.some(argument => argument === 'your argument');
```